# Image scaling and transformation using css3

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I wanted to create a animation where on hovering on a image first it should be scale and transform.

```
#blah - id of that image
```

To achieve the image scaling we can use this css right?

```
#blah{ -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
#blah:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);}
```

But how we can transform after scaling it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using just CSS3 animations, its easy and lightweight, but it all depends on the final effect you want!

I've made this example using only CSS3:

#### [Example at jSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/mLN5y/)

I've also added the click transition, you can tweek the time and `translate`, `scale` and `opacity` attributes of the animation to get the best results for you!

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('http://good-morning.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/thumb1.jpg')"></div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url('http://good-morning.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/thumb2.jpg')"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cont{
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cont:active {
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.cont:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
}
.img {
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    -webkit-transition: scale .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: translate 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.img:hover {
    -webkit-animation: anim 5s 1 ease-out forwards;
    opacity: 1.0;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  12% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translate(-10px, -10px) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -30px) scale(1.1) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer:

```
blah{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

blah:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```